# lazy evaluation in ocaml

Tags: ocaml, lazy-evaluation

I don't understand how could I call `lseq` function so that it will run forever.

```
type 'a llist = LazyList of 'a * (unit -> 'a llist)
let rec lseq nr = 
    LazyList (nr, fun () -> lseq (nr+1))
```

if i call

```
lseq 5
```

I get

```
int llist = LazyList (5, <fun>)
```

Comment: Did you mean: "will _not_ run forever"? Or, let's rephrase your question: "Why a call to the `lseq` function terminates?" Is that what you want to ask?

Comment: well, if i call lseq 5 it gives int llist = LazyList (5, <fun>) didn't it stop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each call to `lseq` will construct a new value of type `'a llist`. The value will consist of two parts. The first part is a list element, produced on this step, and the second one is a function that will produce the rest of the list. Then the function is not called yet, so the function doesn't cycle.

In layman terms, a list is a pair that has one value, and a phone number, where you should call to get the rest.  So if you need more values, you need to call more, e.g.,

```
let rec print_lseq (LazyList (x,next)) = 
  print_int x;
  print_lseq (next ())
```

Of course, this function will never terminate and will print an infinite sequence of numbers.

What concerning your example, `lseq 5` is an infinite sequence that looks like: `5, 6, 7, ...`. It is not eagerly constructed in the memory, but instead it is more like a recipe, how to construct the sequence.